# Interaction between active users and computer - MongoDB / Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a website for a cybercafe and I need to specify that "that particular user" is using "that particular computer". 
This is what I have done so far:

```
    var computerSchema = mongoose.Schema({  
    name: String, 
    type: String, 
    gpu: String,
    cpu: String, 
    memory: String,
    cm: String,
    usedBy : {type: String, default: null},
    active: {type: Boolean, default:false, ref:'user'}

});



 var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 

    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    age: Number,
    address: String,
    mail: String,
    password: String,
    status: String,
    here: {type: Boolean, default:false},
    created_date: Date,
    updated_date: Date,
    active_hash: String,
    role_id: { type: Number, default: 2 }
});

userSchema.virtual('users', {
    ref: 'computer',
    localField:'_id',
    foreignField:'active'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do do this, I think you can delete your `userSchema.virtual`, and update your userSchema to make computer reference on each user like this :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    age: Number,
    address: String,
    mail: String,
    password: String,
    status: String,
    here: {type: Boolean, default:false},
    created_date: Date,
    updated_date: Date,
    active_hash: String,
    role_id: { type: Number, default: 2 },
    computerId: {ref: 'computer'} // Your new reference to a computer _id
});
```

Then, if you want to find a user with his computer, you can use [mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) like this:

```
UsersModel.find().populate('computerId').exec(function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(users); // display users with affected computers if exists
});
```

Hope it helps.